# Add a flag to a git command to be used in a hook

Tags: git

I have a git hook that runs a test whenever I push:

`.git/hooks/pre-push`

```
cd $GOPATH/src/lab.omitted.com/omitted/tools/tribute/
./run-newman-non-dkr.sh
```

I want to have a flag in there so I can push without running the test:

```
if [[ $* == *--skiptest* ]]
then
    echo Skipping Newman Test
else
    echo --- Running Newman Test
    cd $GOPATH/src/lab.omitted.com/omitted/tools/tribute/
    ./run-newman-non-dkr.sh
fi
```

however I can't run `git push` with that flag

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin feature/417/itp-update --skiptest
error: unknown option `skiptest'
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add flags to your push.

**BUT** you can tell git to ignore the hook

> With `--no-verify`, the hook is bypassed completely.

```
git push --no-verify
```

---

Otherwise what you can do is one of the following:

1. Write a configuration file with the desired configuration and read it in your hook
2. Add note `git notes add ....` to your commit with the desired flag and read it again in your hook
3. push your code to a specific branch and skip testing for this branch and if you wish to merge it use a pull request if you can (no clue what is your server)
4. Commit a specific file and if its exist run test whenever git see this file in the commit

Comment: There is some beauty in a good, clear question to which the answer is simply "No"

Answer (score 0):

You can also set variables in the environment, git will pass those through.  Pick some garbled prefix, how about `mghpp` for "my git hook", "pre-push" for starters. Then

```
mghppbypass= git push
```

and in your git hook,

```
if [[ ${mghppbypass+set} = set ]]; then
        echo bypassing pre-push tests
else
        the pre-push tests
fi
```